# Should it be "trusted community members" or "trusted community members."?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

This might be a general SO thing; I don't make edits on many other sites except [MO](http://mathoverflow.com), where I have edit privileges, so I don't know.

I just noticed that the dialogue when I submit an edit says:
[image: Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it's been approved by trusted community members]

> **Thanks for submitting an edit**.  It is only visible to you until it's been approved by trusted community members

Shouldn't there be a period at the end of the sentence?

Comment: If there should, noting it here is adding an unnecessary step to the process of fixing it. Go to [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for anything that is not restricted to only Maths SE.

Comment: @Nij,  don't know whether or not it is restricted only to Math SE, since I don't submit edits anywhere else.  Is it an SO-wide dialogue?

Comment: @Nij Bug reports are fine here, too.  Diamond moderators can attach the [meta-tag:status-review] tag to a post, which will put it into the support queue at a network level.  Not everyone wants (or needs) to have a Meta SE profile.

Comment: Unless there is reason to believe something is site-specific, the default assumption is generic network settings/text/appearance. @LSpice

Comment: Yes, it is technically possible to do that. But why duplicate effort across multiple places for the same issue, if it can be first mentioned on Meta and then shifted back in the less-likely event it is site-specific? @XanderHenderson

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to cause trouble; if this is a network-wide thing, or if I should assume that it is a network-wide thing, then I am fine with closing this question and re-posting it on MetaSE.  Should I do that?

Comment: @Nij Again, the [meta-tag:status-review] tag bumps the question into a network wide queue.  So an issue can be escalated from a local site.  And, again, not everyone wants or needs a Meta SE profile.  As to duplication:  if something is noted on a number of different meta sites, this sends a signal that it is important.  If something is network wide, but only comes up on one site, then it is likely less important / urgent.

Comment: Also, not everyone is *comfortable* posting on the main meta.  The SE network has a reputation for being unwelcoming to newbies.  The main meta, even more so.  We can discuss whether or not these reputations are deserved, but, again, not everyone is comfortable posting on the main meta.

Comment: General bugs and feature requests are always on-topic on per-site metas, @Nij, and always have been. This is perfectly fine on Math Meta. (Chiming in as a Meta.SE regular.)

Comment: No, as others have described above, it's okay to have done here. It may be useful to check on Meta SE whether the issue has been raised already, and add additional information to that, next time. @LSpice

Comment: I will just add that on [meta.se] there is Glorfindel's bug report from March 2020: ['Thanks for submitting an edit' banner is missing a period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345404). (So it is probably at least worth upvoting this network-wide bug report, if you think this is something that should be corrected.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for pointing [that](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34401/should-it-be-trusted-community-members-or-trusted-community-members#comment159652_34401) out.  I have upvoted it.

Comment: That's not at necessarily true, @Mithical. moderator from Meta.se.  Meta.se is well known, for the reason Xander specifies.

Comment: "trusted community members" is not a sentence, so no period is required, but your quoted pop up is in fact a complete sentence which needs to be concluded with a period.

Comment: @amWhy, yes, if you think that the title of the post would be improved by replacing "trusted community members" by "… trusted community members" you are welcome to edit it in.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion here, and upvoted, @LSpice.   Thanks for your post!  (I was only confused at first.) But I completely agree that the text box needs a period.

Comment: @amWhy, thanks.  I do notice that you edited out the text of the message.  I thought it was better to have the text so that it could be found in a text search.  In fact, if we are to keep only one of the image or the text, then I think it is the text that should be included.  Do you think it is better with just the image?

Comment: Good point.  I rolled back to Martin S.'s edit, showing the statement in text.  Thanks for commenting !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing period is missing no more.